# How to create authentication in Laravel for REST API

Tags: php, rest, laravel, authentication, middleware

I am creating REST API using Laravel framework. Everything is great ! But I have one problem with custom Authentication and Authorization.
By default Laravel has some basic authentication in kernel, it is great security layer for desktop/browser apps, but in case of REST API which is used primarily on mobile devices it is redundant.
So I have commented these lines in `Kernel.php`

```
  /*    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,*/
```

Instead I have created my own middleware class and bind it to route

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'auth.token' => \App\Http\Middleware\TokenAuthMiddleware::class,
        'auth.simple' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthBasicMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

I have decided used common approach - token (without OAuth server). Token is issued in response to user credentials one time and than just refreshes when it is required.
My middleware class is just skeleton

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class TokenAuthMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->header());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I am planing to consume token from `Authorization` header, in request and check it if it is valid and not expired allow user to access protected content.
I want to do this in my middleware class.But I have a problem, I am not receiving headers from from request. To test API I use Chrome Extension (Advance Rest Client) or Curl, but neither of them work, I mean client works good but the problem is in laravel, I think.

The problem is that I have manually specefied headers in my request but none of them are appeared in laravel dd -   `dd($request->header());` .

I have tried different headers, they worked, not all,but some of them except `Authorization` header.

Here is an example

```
Request headers 
CSP: active
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
From: asdasdsadsa
Authorization: token=20sadsa
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,uk;q=0.2
Cookie: PHPSESSID=sdotvgu9bvm63b947h5d98nk72; language=ru; currency=UAH
```

And what I get from dd

```
array:9 [
  "host" => array:1 [
    0 => "myhost ip"
  ]
  "connection" => array:1 [
    0 => "keep-alive"
  ]
  "csp" => array:1 [
    0 => "active"
  ]
  "user-agent" => array:1 [
    0 => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36"
  ]
  "from" => array:1 [
    0 => "asdasdsadsa"
  ]
  "accept" => array:1 [
    0 => "*/*"
  ]
  "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
    0 => "gzip, deflate, sdch"
  ]
  "accept-language" => array:1 [
    0 => "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,uk;q=0.2"
  ]
  "cookie" => array:1 [
    0 => "PHPSESSID=myphpsession; language=ru; currency=UAH"
  ]
]
```

As you can see `From` header works, but Authorization header are not present in dump.
For me it seems that laravel is consuming and removing Authorization header before my middleware, even in case I have commented default middlewares for any request.

Please help to solve this problem. Or maybe there is another better approach to authenticate in REST API ? I would be grateful for any suggestion, criticism.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in `Laravel`, but in Apache Web Server configuration file.
Adding this line to the `.htaccess` file into `public` directory.

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

solved the problem.

P.S.

If there other better ways to handle REST API Authorization + Laravel, please leave comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer and I found this link very useful with detailed information and usage for L5 with the use of [JWT LINK](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) .

and second solution is:
[JSON WEB TOKEN](http://jwt.io/)

hop it helps you to.